# Ruby array inserting mystery characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, api, amazon-product-api

this is bizarre.. I'm requesting data from the Amazon Product Advertising API with the Vacuum gem.. and using an array to pass the id it needs.. and for some reason between when I send it, and when the API gets it there is a back slash inserted in the id?? AND its consistently doing it..

```
lookup_items = ['B00HJ50X4W']

puts lookup_items

response = x.item_lookup(
query: {'ItemId' => lookup_items ,
        'ResponseGroup' => 'EditorialReview'
},
persistent: true
)

y = response.to_h
puts y
```

I run the above code and this is the response:

```
B00HJ50X4W
{"Name"=>"ItemId", "Value"=>"[\"B00HJ50X4W\"]"}, {"Name"=>"Operation",     "Value"=>"ItemLookup"}, {"Name"=>"ResponseGroup", "Value"=>"EditorialReview"}, {"Name"=>"Service", "Value"=>"AWSECommerceService"}, {"Name"=>"SignatureMethod", "Value"=>"HmacSHA256"}, {"Name"=>"SignatureVersion", "Value"=>"2"}, {"Name"=>"Timestamp", "Value"=>"2015-05-11T19:51:30Z"}, {"Name"=>"Version", "Value"=>"2013-08-01"}, {"Name"=>"Signature", "Value"=>"F6+Ju5im8CrJW5vjoZpRRqOUK9HO/wIR0NCF2E7lMfM="}]}, "RequestProcessingTime"=>"0.0053020000000000"}, "Items"=>{"Request"=>{"IsValid"=>"True", "ItemLookupRequest"=>{"IdType"=>"ASIN", "ItemId"=>"[\"B00HJ50X4W\"]", "ResponseGroup"=>"EditorialReview", "VariationPage"=>"All"}, "Errors"=>{"Error"=>{"Code"=>"AWS.InvalidParameterValue", "Message"=>"[\"B00HJ50X4W\"] is not a valid value for ItemId. Please change this value and retry your request."}}}}}}
```

is there some way to force it to only be what I send it?? Kinda of at a loss..

Comment: And when I just put in the same id 'B00HJ50X4W' directly and NOT use an array the API request works fine.

Comment: I just saw your comment and updated my answer, guessing at what you really wanted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From both the [Amazon Product Advertising API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) and the [Vacuum gem docs](https://github.com/hakanensari/vacuum#item-lookup), the `ItemId` field is meant to be just a string, so basically when you're passing in `['B00HJ50X4W']` then the Vacuum gem is just calling `.to_s` on it which turns it into a string in the format you're seeing in the response:

```
[30] pry(main)> ['B00HJ50X4W'].to_s
=> "[\"B00HJ50X4W\"]"
```

Fix your parameter and you'll fix your problem.

#### Update

I just noticed your comment, and so you obviously knew how to make this work all along, so now I'm guessing that you actually wanted to know how to request the item information for multiple items?

You should edit your question to make that clear, and then the answer to **that** question is [(as the API says)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html): *"For more than one ID, use a comma-separated list of up to ten IDs."* So:

```
lookup_items = ['B00HJ50X4W', 'OTHER_ID', 'YET_ANOTHER_ID']

response = x.item_lookup(
query: {'ItemId' => lookup_items.join(","),
        'ResponseGroup' => 'EditorialReview'
},
persistent: true
)
```

Ie. you actually make a single string, with commas between the IDs.

Comment: thanks for the extra info!! No, I was at a loss.. I didn't realize it was converting my array to a string.. I'm still pretty much a Noob.. this is my first time trying to write an app!

Comment: Ok, weird that you knew how to make it work but wanted to persist with using the array. But, glad to help, I'll leave my update here in case someone else stumbles onto your question wanting the multiple IDs answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no backslashes. `\"` is how you write `"` in a double quoted string. IOW, `"\""` is the same as `'"'`.

Comment: Sure.. but it still seems to be inserting characters.. its weird.. because if just put in that id directly.. I get this.. 

"ItemLookupRequest"=>{"IdType"=>"ASIN", "ItemId"=>"B00HJ50X4W",